# Problem installing Woeusb

Tags: package-management, software-installation, usb, windows, woeusb

I'm trying to install [woeusb](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) and this is happening all the time:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 woeusb : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
dimitri@dimitri-OptiPlex-780:~$
```

I don't know what to do

Comment: Until this problem with `woeusb` is solved, you can use **mkusb-plug** according to this link:

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug)

Comment: Why has this question been closed? None of the linked issues are relevant to this particular case